# need to free a mutex?

Tags: c, free, mutex, init

I have a very simple (sample) C program as follows.  I want to ensure I release any resources necessary so that valgrind does not complain.  Do I need to free mutex1?  Or do anything before the program terminates?  Or is the mutex1 not allocate memory?

```
02  pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
03  int counter=0;
04   
05  /* Function C */
06  void functionC()
07  {
08     pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
09     counter++
10     pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
11  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is fine as it is.  It is not necessary to use pthread_mutex_destroy on a statically allocated mutex.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to free `mutex1`. `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is a macro that *hides* a struct initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

mutex1 in your code is a global variable rather than a heap-allocated variable. You do not need to free it. The OS will free all resources that your app use when you app terminate.